# MKMapView linker error

Tags: iphone, mapkit, android-mapview

I have upgraded my iphone sdk from 2.2.1 to 3.0. I downloaded a sample code for MapKit and was able to run it successfully. But when I tried to write my own program I faced linker errors.

The error is not thrown when I import MapKit/MapKit.h or when I declare a variable as MKMapView *mapView; I get the error when I say [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

I have added Mapkit framework in my project. I am able to see it under Frameworks. When I expand it I am able to see the header files as well. I added it from /Developer/Platforms/iphone.OS.Platform/Developer/SDKs/iphoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Framework/Mapkit.framework.
I also observed that the other frameworks that are present under Frameworks have some small lock sort of icon. But the MapKit.framework doesn't have it.

Can someone tell me if I have added the Mapkit.framework from the wrong place? If so from which path should I add it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your path seems correct, /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework

Did you check if it was added to your current target?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your target SDK is 3.0 and not 2.0...